# system lookup error undefined symbol SFML

Tags: c++, linux, sfml

I am running Linux Mint 12 on an i686.

I am running a program that uses SFML. I compile and run it as such:

```
    g++ -c lineTest.cpp Rasterizer.cpp simpleCanvas.cpp
    g++ -o lineTest lineTest.o Rasterizer.o simpleCanvas.o -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

After when I try to run the program lineTest, I get the following error:

```
$ ./lineTest
./lineTest: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so.1.6: undefined 
symbol: _ZN2sf7Unicode11UTF8OffsetsE
```

I'm not using any IDE, just running everything from the command line. Does anyone know what I can do to get rid of the error and get the program to run?

Comment: Are your sfml binaries (`.so`) updated?

Comment: @MM. I just installed sfml a few days ago. How do I update it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I had to guess I would say you have sfml in both /usr/lib and /usr/local/lib. Decoding the mangled name:

```
> c++filt _ZN2sf7Unicode11UTF8OffsetsE
sf::Unicode::UTF8Offsets
```

so, libsfml-window.so looks for the `sf::Unicode::UTF8Offsets` function but cannot find it.

Comment: I just checked and yes, I do have libsfml libraries installed in both /usr/lib/ and /usr/local/lib. How do I fix this? Should I just rm the libsfml files from one of the directories? If so, which one should I delete them from?

Comment: I just removed them from the /usr/local/lib directory, and it worked.

Comment: Removing from /usr/local/lib was the right idea since /usr/lib contains the system libraries.